# multiple UL's not same level

Tags: html, list, css, html-lists

I've got a problem with the position of two UL's. I want the two UL's to be on the same level. As you can see in the Picture below, the first UL list is way down, while the second is at the top. I was able to recreate this on jsfiddle.

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/5krJU/

I was able to figure out that the problem is because the second list has more li than the first, but i wasn't able to fix it.

My current css looks like this:

```
#container {text-align: center; display:block;}
#container > ul { color:#776; display:inline-block; width:360px; list-style-type: none;}
```

and my html like this:

```
<div id="container">
 <ul>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
 </ul>
 <ul>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Here's a picture of it:
[image: my problem]

### Update

i found out the answer.

Solution would be adding 'vertical-align: top;' to the ul's.

Please close this question.

Sorry for the inconvience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since they are inline-blocks, you need to adjust the vertical alignment.

http://jsfiddle.net/5krJU/1/

**CSS**

```
#container > ul {
  color:#776;
  display:inline-block;
  width:60px;
  list-style-type: none;
  vertical-align: top
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you just need to `float: left` the lists. This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NAA6Y/2/) should make everything clear.
Cheers!

Comment: Using float:left; wouldn't center the UL